# How to count number of entries, annotate it and select latest with Django ORM

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-orm

I need to select entries which match specific pattern, count them and the pick latest. How to do this via Django ORM?

Tried:

```
Entry.objects.filter(A=B).annotate(Count("something")).latest("date")
```

This counts only 1 item for each B. If I remove `latest("date")`, it counts correctly but gives only count number and nothing else. How to perform this task correctly?

**UPD:** Actual code

```
def render_entries(request):
    ids = Entry.objects.values("entry_token").distinct()
    entries = [Entry.objects.filter(entry_token=x["entry_token"]).annotate(count=Count("id")).latest("date_time") for x in ids]
    return render(request, "entries_list.html", {'entries':entries})
```

Comment: Why not just to split it in two sentences?

Comment: Sounds like two different queries

Comment: UPD: your code looks like anti-patterns sample.

Comment: @danihp Thanks for your observation, helps alot!

Comment: So what is not working if you do `entries = [Entry.objects.filter(entry_token=x["entry_token"]).annotate(count=Count("id")).order_by("-date_time").first() for x in ids]`

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev It gives 1 as counter for every row, while I need actual number of entries.

Comment: Read my updated answer. I don't think it is possible to do in one query.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev Thank you for your solution. Unfortunately it's not oneliner, but so far I'll stick to it. Btw, this is workaround for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40127698/how-to-get-latest-unique-entries-from-sqlite-db-with-the-counter-of-entries-via , maybe you know better way to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated** Probably not most optimal, but this should work.

```
def render_entries(request):
    # get list of all entry_tokens with count
    tokens = Entry.objects.values('entry_token').annotate(count=Count('entry_token'))
    # create list of entries
    entries = []
    for token in tokens:
        entry = Entry.objects.filter(entry_token=token['entry_token']).latest('date_time')
        entry.count = token['count']
        entries.append(entry)
    return render(request, "entries_list.html", {'entries':entries})
```

Comment: result is the same as provided in question.

Comment: @wasd show us your exact code. There is no way it returns only count number.

Comment: It returns not only count number - it counts only 1 item

Comment: @wasd Ah. Understood change `"something"` to `"id"`. And this should solve your problem.

Comment: No changes at all, for some reason

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126327/discussion-between-wasd-and-sardorbek-imomaliev).